# Surface of graph of a function.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

> Let $G:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:|x|<|z|^2,|y|<|z|,0<z<1\}$ and $f:G\to\mathbb{R},f(x,y,z)=2x+2y+z^3$. Calculate the surface of the graph of f.

We recently got introduced to Stokes' theorem and the Divergence theorem, but I'm still struggling immensely with applying it. I think this a problem I have to apply the Divergence theorem to, but I'm completely lost and need help.

After thinking about it more I found the following:

We have the function $f:G\to\mathbb{R}$. So we can define our Manifold $M$ as the image of $\phi:G\to\mathbb{R}^4,x\mapsto (x,f(x))$, which therefore is of dimension 3. We see that $D\phi^TD\phi=1+Df^TDf$. Thus we have that the area of the graph of $f$ is the surface of $M$, given by $\int_M dS_3=\int_G\sqrt{det(1+Df^TDf)}\,d\lambda_k(x)=\int_G3\sqrt{z^4+1}\,d\lambda_k(x)$. Then, we see that $G=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:-z^2<x<z^2,-z<y<z,0<z<1\}$. Solving the integral gives us the answer $2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you mean calculate the surface integral of $f$ in the graph of $f$?

Comment: This is the exact wording of the problem. The surface of $f$ is 3-dimensional. My thoughts were that I have to define $F(x,y,z)=(x,y,z,f(x,y,z))$ and then use one of the theorems.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's 2-dimensional, that's why you could (depending on what you want to compute) use the divergence or Stokes's theorem. Actually you have a whole family of surfaces, given by $2x+2y+z^3 =c$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm still lost at what the question wants.

Comment: Why is it 2-dimensional? If you plot a 2-dimensional function $f(x,y)$, you get a 3-dimensional graph $(x,y,f(x,y))$. Thus its surface is 2-dimensional.

Comment: Okay, perhaps this additional comment will enlighten us. The graph of $f$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^4$, which the surface defined implicitly by $f$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and what more, it is 2 dimensional. For comparison, think of $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$ which is the family of spheres centered at the origin.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. You're using in the first sense I mentioned in the previous comment. Can't use Stokes's or Divergence theorems since they apply in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Actually, the Divergence theorem applies in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12714/discussion-between-fantini-and-blst)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each point $(x,y,z)$ in $D$ we get a number $\mathrm{f}(x,y,z)$ given by 
$$\mathrm{f}(x,y,z)=2x+2y+z^3$$
The graph of the function $\mathrm{f} : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is, for ${\bf x} = (x,y,z)$, *defined to be* as follows:

$$\{({\bf x},v) \in D \times \mathbb{R} : v=\mathrm{f}({\bf x})\}$$
This is the usual definition that we are used. For example, in the plane, the graph of $x^2$ is given by
$$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y = x^2 \}$$

You need to describe the graph of your $\mathrm{f}$ given the unusual nature of $D$.

I would start by looking looking at the boundary cases, e.g. $|x| = |z|^2$, $|y|=|z|$ and $z=0$ or $z=1$.

Comment: As we figured out above, we have that the graph of $f$ is $(x,y,z,2x+2y+z^3)$ where $(x,y,z)\in D$ which lives in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and thus it's surface is 3-dimensional. After this, I'm still lost.

Comment: @blst As you can tell by the time I posted my reply: I was busy typing your reply while your comments conversation was underway. I would recommend that you start by looking at the boundary cases: $|x|=|z|^2$, $|y|=|z|$ and $z=0$ or $z=1$.

Comment: For the boundary cases we have $z=0$, then $x=0,y=0$. You pointed out $z=1$. If we have $x=\pm 1$, we have $z=1$. Same with $y$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: @blst Let $z=t$ where $0 < t < 1$ then ask yourself what $|y|<|z|$ and $|x|<|z|^2$ give you for each $t$. Then, what does that translate to in $(x,y,z,2x+2y+z^3)$? Other than actually answering the question, I don't see what else I can say.

Comment: Well, I'm still completely lost. I think it would help to see an actual answer to this.

Comment: @blst How much time and thought have you given to this problem? I have given you a solution. Try *thinking* about it. What exactly do you expect? For me to solve your problem for you? (I will not do your homework for you. Sorry.) For me to write one line and then you suddenly understand? I would be a millionaire if I could make people understand university mathematics without them having to think.

Comment: The thing is I don't even know _what_ im supposed to integrate here.

Comment: @blst You haven't been asked to integrate. You have been asked to find a surface. That will mean the boundary of a region. Stokes' Theorem relates an integral over a region to another integral over a boundary:

$$\int_{R} \mathrm{d}\omega = \int_{\partial R} \omega$$

Before you can even try to use this, you need to find the boundary of the region, i.e. find the $\partial R$. As far as I can tell, the graph of $\mathrm{f}$ is the region $R$ and you need to find the boundary $\partial R$.

Comment: The surface should be ${(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:z=1,|x|<|z|^2,|y|<|z|\}\union\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:0<z<1,|x|=|z|^2,|y|=|z|}. I think it's a half-ellipsoid.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not an answer, but just to clarify the problem  after reading the comments above, let's read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface: "In mathematics ... a surface is a two-dimensional ... manifold. The most familiar examples are those that arise as the boundaries of solid objects in ordinary three-dimensional Euclidean space R3 — for example, the surface of a ball".

The graph of $f$ defined above is a 3-dimensional region (living in $\mathbb{R}^4$) and bounded by the surfaces we are asked to "calculate".